# Focus on the element to scroll on load of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to focus/activate a container through javascript, so that I can scroll it by using up and down arrow keys. Currently, this is not possible until I click on that container.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/s0tjocwk/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: auto;
}
.child {
    height: 800px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

I tried using `Element.focus()` method of javascript which didn't work.

Comment: Purpose of jQuery tag???

Comment: @A.Wolff I thought there is a solution using it. Just similar to as I mentioned javascript tag.

Comment: Anything that can be done in jQuery can be done in javascript ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `tabindex` attribute in order to get DIV element focusable, e.g:

```
<div class="main" tabindex="-1">
```

Then for styling purpose, you could wish to set `outline` CSS property:

```
.main {
    outline: 0;
    ...
}
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: Thanks for the solution. but this is not working when I apply using javascript. Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/s0tjocwk/3/). Sorry, I didn't mention that I have many similar containers on the page and I need to activate a single container.

Comment: @Mr_Green You still need to call `main.focus();` of course, `tabindex` doesn't magically set focus: http://jsfiddle.net/s0tjocwk/4/  ***As a side note*** This should be possible in future to use `autofocus` attribute for not only input elments but AFAIK, none browser currently support it for DIV element